# Sharepoint crawler data and SPList data mutual access

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-crawler, splist

In our sharepoint system, we have document library labeled as **My Documents** and complex file structure labeled as **All documents**.
This All documents are indexed by crawler and each user can access data from all documents via search and his document library (My Document one).

I need the same functionality on both of them (download them zipped, copy them etc.) and I don't want to same thing in two ways, because of different system.

Is there some way to treat both "repositories" in the same way in term of abstraction? Like if I will have some class Repository and it will get `IQueryables` from both MyDocuments and AllDocuments and perform the same task on them?

I Found that both of them can have their items viewed as `DataTable`. Is it a good solution to do it that way? I prefer Rather `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` for those particular tasks I need to implement

Btw. I'm implementing it in csharp

Comment: What do you mean by a "complex file structure"?

Comment: @Rawling With complex file structure I mean many folders and subfolders - Thousands of folders for companies, in which are tens to hundreds subfolders for different projects etc. That's not the problem, because it is indexed by crawler and I'm working with them via Crawler results.

Comment: Are these folders and subfolders in a document library?

Comment: @Rawling: Basically yes, but I need the power of crawler to select filtered data. I think I forget to mention that in All Documents I need to work with filtered data, which was filtered by crawler. 

And of course I will work in multple folders simultaneosly and doing it all with SPLists and similar will be huge pain and I'm not even talking about performance issues.